# Autocomplete not working in Terminal local to folder

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

When I go into any folder via `cd` and then press `tab` a whole list of options is displayed. How do I make the autocomplete local to the folder?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see only binaries in the current folder, press `./tab` (dot slash tab).

If you want to see all folders in the current folder, press `cd tab`

In your screenshot, pressing`m tab` is showing all binaries that start with m found in the path.

In all cases, pressing tab a second time will show all matches if there are more than one.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for `bash-completion`. [This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34917/212526) describes how to get it (tl;dr - for an easy install you'll need a package manager like Homebrew or MacPorts) for example:

```
brew install bash_completion
```

With `bash-completion`, typing `cd` and then Tab the results you get should be limited to folders.

Out-of-the-box `bash-completion` covers a wide range of possible completions, but there may be more - check your package manager. For example, on Homebrew try this:

```
brew search completions
```

This returns additional completions for macOS tools like `open` and `launchctl`, virtualisation tools like `docker` and `vagrant`, and many others.

You *can* create your own completions, for example I use this one to show me *only* `.png` files for a script (`png2icns`) I hacked together.

```
complete -f -X '!*.png' png2icns
```

However this really isn't necessary for most cases - `bash-completion` will cover all the common uses.

For completeness I need to mention that fans of the `zsh` shell will no doubt tell you that `zsh`'s support for completion is far superior to `bash`'s! Personally, `bash` does what I need, albeit with a little help from `brew`.